# GitHub REST API for getting repo's all open pull requests COUNT without downloading them

Tags: rest, github

I'm trying to find a GitHub APIs for open pull requests count, without downloading them. ()
I looked through GitHub search API and repos API
https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues-and-pull-requests
https://api.github.com/repos/pulls?state=open
But wasn't able to find here.

[example of big repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooSE5.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search for PRs, you can use issues search with `is:pr` modifier:

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=rockstars%20state:open%20is:pr

The `total_count` field of the response is what you need.

Comment: One more question. I was looking for search API commits section as well. (to get all commits count of given repository) https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-commits#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories  They present a search query, but when I'm trying to get with my given username and repos in the query repo:USERNAME/REPO I'm getting a validation issue.

Comment: Looks like this is due to the fact that you can't use search to get ALL commits. You should provide a search string (beside the repo and user name). So for example this will NOT work: 
https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:1int/rockstars , but it works fine when added a "test" search string to it: https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=repo:1int/rockstars+test

Comment: I'm getting a message -  you must specify a custom media type in the 'Accept' header. Please see the docs for full details.",

Comment: Oh, I assumed you did that. Yes, you would need to specify a header in your HTTP request. The header name is "Accept" and the value should be "application/vnd.github.cloak-preview". It's done differently depending on your tool set. For example, in PHP you'd write: header("Accept", "application/vnd.github.cloak-preview").